# Setting up project with input and output practice

Tags: angular

I have the following code which I will post on GitHub.

I am getting an error saying:

```
Can't export directive ParentComponent from ParentModule as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

Project structure:

[image]

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ChildModule,
      ParentModule,
      HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

parent.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [ParentComponent ],
    providers: [],

})
export class ParentModule { }
```

child.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChildComponent
    ],
    imports: [
       CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [ChildComponent],
    providers: [],

})
export class ChildModule {}
```

Now how I want to be the `home` and the default page:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],

})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Git Link: [GitHub](https://github.com/drewjocham/InputOutputHelp.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do both declar and export for the parent module as well as you did for the chield

```
parent.ts

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ParentComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    exports: [ParentComponent ],
    providers: [],

})
export class ParentModule { }
```

Comment: the best way is to put all your component, pipes, directive which are common in  shared direct and share it across the project